# What is the easiest 2D game library to use with Scala?

Tags: scala, game-engine, scala-2.9, 2d-games

I need to integrate a scala library for reinforcement learning that works on scala 2.9.1 with a 2D game library. If it uses SBT that would be awesome.

I was looking at scage, however the current master branch is broken, it works on maven, and the examples for how to set up a starter project simply did not work.

I am not opposed to using a java library directly, but I really want to mimize the amount of work needed to get started.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) is a pretty popular Java-based 2D library/engine, built on top of LWJGL.

Comment: Is this Scala RF library public? Can you give me a pointer to it?

Answer (score 0):

How about ScalaFX?

- [At GitHub](https://github.com/scalafx)
- [JavaFX and Scala like milk and cookies](http://www.slideshare.net/steveonjava/javafx-and-scala-like-milk-and-cookies)

Comment: Could anyone share sample sbt configuration for scalafx on Linux host?